# New CSV by combining 2 csv files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have 2 CSV files that has

File1:

```
Column1,column2
data1, data2
```

File2:

```
Column3,column4, column5,column6
data3,data4,data5,data6
```

I have to create a new CSV file that combines both columns from file 1 with the 1st and 3rd columns from file 2 (4 total columns).

```
Column1,column2,column3,column5
data1,data2,data3,data5
```

I am looking to do this using batch file commands. Any suggestions?

Code i am using helps me copy one file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=," %%a IN (file1.csv) DO (
 ECHO(%%a,%%c
)
)>new.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: How are the files related? Do they share a column? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: File 1 has column A,B and file 2 has column c,d,e,f. now i like to create a file that has only columns a,b,c,e . these 2 files are not related,

Answer (score 0):

How about following script?

File1.csv :

```
column1,column2
data1,data2
data3,data4
data5,data6
```

File2.csv :

```
column3,column4,column5,column6
data3,data4,data5,data6
data7,data8,data9,data10
```

Script :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ct1=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File1.csv) do (
    set /a ct1+=1
    set ar1[!ct1!]=%%i
)

set ct2=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File2.csv) do (
    set /a ct2+=1
    set ar2[!ct2!]=%%i
)

if !ct1! lss !ct2! (
    set ct=!ct2!
) else (
    set ct=!ct1!
)

for /l %%i in (1,1,!ct!) do (
    echo !ar1[%%i]!,!ar2[%%i]!>> new.csv
)
```

new.csv :

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
data3,data4,data7,data8,data9,data10
data5,data6,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure batch solution that works, but with the following limitations and or assumptions:

- File 1 lines are terminated by carriage return and linefeed (Windows style)
- File 1 lines are no longer than 1021 bytes
- File 2 must have a value for each column (no consecutive commas)
- File 2 line lengths never exceed ~8191 bytes
- File 2 does not have any quoted column values that include commas.
- Files 1 and 2 have the same number of lines
- Neither file has quoted data values that include new lines (rare, but possible within a CSV).

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
<"file1.csv" >"merged.csv" (
  for /f "usebackq eol=, delims=, tokens=1,3" %%A in ("file2.csv") do (
    set /p "part1="
    set "part2=%%A,%%B"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !part1!,!part2!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

A much more robust and faster solution is possible if you use PowerShell, JScript, or VBS.

You can also implement an efficient and robust solution using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help.

This JREPL solution has only the following reasonable limitations:

- Files 1 and 2 must have the same number of lines
- Neither file has quoted data values that include new lines

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "col=\q(?:\q\q|[^,\q])*\q|[^,]*"
call jrepl "^(%col%),(?:%col%),(%col%)(?:,.*|$)" ^
           "$txt=stdin.ReadLine()+','+$1+','+$2" ^
           /jq /x /f "file2.csv" /o "merged.csv" <"file1.csv"
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The files do not have equal number of lines and file2 has quoted values. Is it possible to add a column to a existing file, like just coping column 1 and 3 from file2 and add it next to column 2 of file 1.

Comment: @Dinesh - You need to define how you want to handle files with different number of lines. Quotes are not a problem in and of themselves, but quoted commas are problematic with pure batch. It can be solved, but I would use JREPL instead.

Answer (score 0):

This  flexible script does what you want, given that the following restrictions are not violated:

- both files must contain the same number of lines;
- the number of columns per line/row must be equal per each file;
- lines are no longer than 1023 bytes, including the terminating line-break;
- field/cell values must not contain line-breaks;
- each line/row must be terminated by Windows-style line-breaks (CR+LF);
- the given column numbers to copy must be sorted in ascending order;

So here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE1=%~dp0File1.csv" & rem // (1st input CSV file; state `%~1` to use 1st arg.)
set "_FILE2=%~dp0File2.csv" & rem // (2nd input CSV file; state `%~2` to use 2nd arg.)
set "_COLS1=1,2"            & rem // (ascending list of columns to copy from 1st file)
set "_COLS2=1,3"            & rem // (ascending list of columns to copy from 2nd file)
set "_SEPAR=,"              & rem // (separator character, usually `,`)

rem // Main routine:
4< "%_FILE1%" 3< "%_FILE2%" (
    call :READLINE
)

endlocal
exit /B


:READLINE
    rem // Read a line of both files:
    set "LINE1=" & set "LINE2="
    <&4 set /P LINE1=""
    <&3 set /P LINE2=""
    rem // Terminate sub-routine in case both lines are empty:
    if not defined LINE1 if not defined LINE2 exit /B
    rem // Process lines:
    call :PROCESS LINE1 LINE2
    rem // Repeat reading:
    goto :READLINE
    exit /B


:PROCESS  ref_string1  ref_string2
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "BUF=%_SEPAR%"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Test both strings against global wild-card characters:
    set "STR1=!%~1!" & set "STR2=!%~2!"
    if "!STR1:**=!!STR2:**=!"=="!STR1!!STR2!" goto :PROCESS_CONT
    if "!STR1:*?=!!STR2:*?=!"=="!STR1!!STR2!" goto :PROCESS_CONT
    if "!STR1:*<=!!STR2:*<=!"=="!STR1!!STR2!" goto :PROCESS_CONT
    if "!STR1:*>=!!STR2:*>=!"=="!STR1!!STR2!" goto :PROCESS_CONT
    >&2 echo(ERROR: Illegal character encountered^^!
    exit /B 1
    :PROCESS_CONT
    rem // Prepare line strings for being processed by a standard `for` loop:
    set "STR1=!STR1:"=""!^"
    set "STR2=!STR2:"=""!^"
    set "STR1="!STR1:%_SEPAR%=","!""
    set "STR2="!STR2:%_SEPAR%=","!""
    rem // `for /F` loops to transport prepared line strings beyond `endlocal`:
    for /F "delims=" %%E in (^""!STR1!"^") do (
        for /F "delims=" %%F in (^""!STR2!"^") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Process 1st line string:
            set /A "IDX=0"
            for %%I in (%%~E) do (
                rem // Compare column index of current item with given column list:
                set /A "IDX+=1" & set "FND="
                for %%J in (%_COLS1%) do (
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    if !IDX! EQU %%J (
                        endlocal & set "FND=#"
                    ) else endlocal
                )
                rem // Matching column index encountered, so assemble output line:
                if defined FND (
                    set "NEW=%%~I%_SEPAR%"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "delims=" %%K in (^""!BUF!!NEW!"^") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "BUF=%%~K"
                    )
                )
            )
            rem // Process 1st line string:
            set /A "IDX=0"
            for %%I in (%%~F) do (
                rem // Compare column index of current item with given column list:
                set /A "IDX+=1" & set "FND="
                for %%J in (%_COLS2%) do (
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    if !IDX! EQU %%J (
                        endlocal & set "FND=#"
                    ) else endlocal
                )
                rem // Matching column index encountered, so assemble output line:
                if defined FND (
                    set "NEW=%%~I%_SEPAR%"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "delims=" %%K in (^""!BUF!!NEW!"^") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "BUF=%%~K"
                    )
                )
            )
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    rem // Return output line buffer:
    echo(!BUF:~1,-1!
    endlocal
    endlocal
    exit /B
```